# Unable to sort multiple lines

Tags: python, sorting

My aim: to sort multiple lines in a text file using Python

**Method**

A sample file has been created and this is used to test the Python script

*Code:*

```
f = open("C:\\sample.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
print(lines)
print(lines.sort)
```

*Sample.txt*

```
gg
bb
aa
cc
ii
ff
```

**Results**

The current Python script does not work as expected

*Current*

```
c:\Temp>C:\sort_by_url.py
['gg\nbb\naa\ncc\nii\nff']
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x000000000227BE48>
```

*Expected*

```
aa
bb
cc
ff
gg
ii
```

Comment: your split is wrong. You should directly use readlines instead of read

Comment: I think you should also do `split('\n')`

Comment: @LtWorf Question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `list.sort` function.

try this

```
lines.sort()
print lines
```

`list.sort` perform operation on same object. If you don't want to change original list, then you can create sorted list using `sorted(list)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
file_name = open('Sample.txt','rb')
new_list = list(file_name)[0].split(',')
new_list = sorted(new_list)
for items in new_list:
    print items
Output:
aa
bb
cc
ff
gg
ii
```

If your file doesn't contain any ',' then your sample input is 
gg
bb
..
then try this

```
file_name = open('input1.txt','rb')
new_list = []
for items in file_name:
    if items != '\n':
        items = items.replace("\r\n", "")
    new_list.append(items)
new_list = sorted(new_list)
for i in new_list:
    print i

Output:
aa
bb
cc
ff
gg
ii
```

Comment: `File "C:\sort_by_url.py", line 16, in <module>
    new_list = list(file_name)[0].split(',')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API`

Comment: give a sample input of how your file looks like @utrecht

Comment: Output of the latter: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sort_by_url.py", line 17, in <module>
    items = items.replace("\r\n", "")
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object`

Comment: Sample file is defined in the question