# Unable to sort multiple lines on last string of line

Tags: python, sorting

**Introduction**

Follow up to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157542/unable-to-sort-multiple-lines).

**Aim:** sort multiple lines on last string

**Method**

A sample file has been created to test the sorting of multiple lines on last String.

*Sample*

```
aa - http://gggggggggg
bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb
cc - http://aaaaaaaaaa
aa - http://cccccccccc
bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb
cc - http://iiiiiiiiii
bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb
aa - http://ffffffffff
bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb
```

*Code*

```
fp = "C:\\sample.txt"
fp2 = "C:\\sample2.txt"

with open(fp, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.sort()
    print(lines)

with open(fp2, "r+") as f2:
    f2.write("\n".join(lines))
```

**Results**

The sorting is based on the first string, rather than on the latter

*Current*

```
aa - http://cccccccccc

aa - http://ffffffffff

aa - http://gggggggggg

bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb
bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb

bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb

bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb

cc - http://aaaaaaaaaa

cc - http://iiiiiiiiii
```

*Expected*

```
cc - http://aaaaaaaaaa

bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb
bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb

bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb

bb - http://bbbbbbbbbb


aa - http://cccccccccc

aa - http://ffffffffff

aa - http://gggggggggg

cc - http://iiiiiiiiii
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lines.sort(key= lambda x:x.split()[-1]) # sort on last item of each string
```

For example:

```
In [11]: s ="cc - http://iiiiiiiiii "

In [12]: s.split()
Out[12]: ['cc', '-', 'http://iiiiiiiiii']  # this is what x:x.split()[-1] is doing each time
```

I would also  use `with open(fp, "r+") as f` and `with open(fp2, "r+")as f1` to open your files, it closes them automatically for you.

Comment: The advice regarding the `with open` has been added to the question

Answer (score 1):

[Use the `key` parameter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) to specify the proxy value on which to sort. In this case you could split on the `'-'`, and reverse the order of the substrings:

```
fp = "C:\\sample.txt"
fp2 = "C:\\sample2.txt"

with open(fp, "r+") as f, open(fp2, "r+") as f2:
    lines = sorted(f, key=lambda text: text.split('-', 1)[::-1])
    print(lines)
    f2.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: The code has been executed but the sample2.txt remains empty

Comment: I had a stray `readlines()` call in the code above which should have been omitted. The code should now work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is an idiom called "decorate, sort, undecorate."

Loop through your lines, and for each one make a tuple of "last string", "complete line".

Sort that list of tuples.

Return only the "complete line" portion of each tuple.

Example:

```
fp = "C:\\sample.txt"
fp2 = "C:\\sample2.txt"

with open(fp, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    line_tuples = [(i.split()[-1], i) for i in lines]
    line_tuples.sort()
    lines = [i[-1] for i in line_tuples]
    print(lines)

with open(fp2, "r+") as f2:
    f2.write("\n".join(lines))
```

The two list comprehensions, on either side of `line_tuples.sort()`, may be hard to read because they do so much in such short space.  The first one basically says "for each string in `lines`, create a matching tuple in `line_tuples` which starts with just the last word of the string."  That last word of the string becomes the sorting key in the next line.  Then the second list comprehension says "Go through all those tuples, extract just the original lines, and put them back in `lists`."

Note that this code *should* work, but I don't have access to a machine with Python at the moment, so I can't guarantee it.

Comment: Could you add an example to illustrate the answer?