# Sort on last element of inconsistent number of elements list

Tags: python, sorting

**Introduction**

Follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159935/unable-to-sort-multiple-lines-on-last-string-of-line).

**Aim:** sort on last element of inconsistent number of elements list

**Methods**

*Code*

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

for fn in os.listdir(cwd):
    print(fn)

    with open(fn, "r+") as f, open(cwd + "\\all.txt", "r+") as f2:
        lines = sorted(f, key=lambda text: text.split('-', 1)[::-1])
        print(lines)

        my_new_list = [fn + " - " + x for x in lines]
        print (my_new_list)

        f2.write("\n".join(my_new_list))
```

*Sample*

```
aa - http://cc
bb - http://bb
cc - http://aa
aa - aa - http://cc
bb - bb - http://bb
cc - cc - http://aa
aa - aa - aa - http://cc
bb - bb - bb - http://bb
cc - cc - cc - http://aa
```

**Output**

The list is not sorted on the last element. It seems that the sorting took place on the second element.

*Current*

```
sample.txt - aa - aa - aa - http://cc

sample.txt - aa - aa - http://cc

sample.txt - bb - bb - bb - http://bb

sample.txt - bb - bb - http://bb

sample.txt - cc - cc - cc - http://aa
sample.txt - cc - cc - http://aa

sample.txt - cc - http://aa

sample.txt - bb - http://bb

sample.txt - aa - http://cc
```

*Expected*

```
sample.txt - cc - http://aa
sample.txt - cc - cc - http://aa
sample.txt - cc - cc - cc - http://aa

sample.txt - bb - http://bb
sample.txt - bb - bb - http://bb
sample.txt - bb - bb - bb - http://bb

sample.txt - aa - http://cc
sample.txt - aa - aa - http://cc
sample.txt - aa - aa - aa - http://cc
```

Comment: Did you even test what you were doing? For example, `"cc - cc - cc - http://aa".split('-', 1)[::-1] == [' cc - cc - http://aa', 'cc ']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `text.split('-', 1)` which only splits the string once (at the *first* `'-'`).

You actually want to split in the *last* `'-'` so you want want `text.rsplit('-', 1)`

*Note, `rsplit`, rather than `split` :-)

Answer (score 1):

To sort based on the last element, you can use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) like this

```
lines = sorted(f, key=lambda text: text.rsplit('-', 1)[1])
```